# Problems with getline c++

Tags: c++14, getline

I have been searching for a few hours now, but have yet to come across my problem. I am reading from a file first line would be the number of movies and the lines after that would be the movie title, director, etc.

Example:

```
2
Friday Night Lights: Upcoming;Bond, James;2061;128;93000000;871530324
Friday Night Lights: Upcoming;Bond, James;2061;128;93000000;871530324
```

but I can't seem to get the getline function to work properly. I've tried it a few different ways but it just doesn't work.

```
struct MovieData{
string movieTitle;
string director;
int yearReleased;
double runningTime;
double costOfProduction;
double revenueGenerated;
double profitOrLoss;
};
void storingMovieData(ifstream file, MovieData array[], int numberOfMovies);

int main(){
    char fileName[50];
    MovieData array[];
    cout << "Enter file name: ";
    cin.getline(fileName, 50);
    int numberOfMovies;
    ifstream file(fileName);
    file >> numberOfMovies;
    storingMovieData(file, array, numberOfMovies)

    file.close();

    return 0;
}

void storingMovieData(ifstream file, MovieData array[], int numberOfMovies){
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfMovies; i++){
    getline(file, array[i].movieTitle, ';');
    getline(file, array[i].director, ';');
    getline(file, array[i].yearReleased, ';');
    getline(file, array[i].runningTime, ';');
    getline(file, array[i].costOfProduction, ';');
    getline(file, array[i].revenueGenerated, ';');
    getline(file, array[i].profitOrLoss, ';');
   }
}
```

Any help on my issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `failbit` after you call `istream::getline`? Have you used a step-through debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the root of your problem:

```
int yearReleased;
double runningTime;
double costOfProduction;
double revenueGenerated;
double profitOrLoss;
```

`getline()` doesn't accept double/int.

You'll probably want to read into some temp strings and later assign to struct after converting to double.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know, but now I do!